# How to build imported project on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, build

I just imported source folders and required libraries from another PC on which I had been working. The project contains JAVA and Python code in separate packages. Now there seems to be some problem with running the Java parts.

**`Error: Could not find or load main class Drivers.DependencyFinder`**

I have tried Cleaning and Building the project. It didn't create any classes in the bin folder. When I copied class files from the older PC, it gives some version error.

I'd like to make a fresh build, removing all the things I had earlier other than the source code. Clicking Build All or Build doesn't produce anything. What's going wrong?

Comment: Looks like you might miss some plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the project properties and check Source tab under Java Build Path. Make sure the proper folders are included in the build path.